# If number is not null

Tags: null, crystal-reports

I have function which returns the last instance of "percent" field but the last few values are null. I need it to not include these null values and return the most recent/last not null value. I have changed the setting to default values for null and `{Command.percent}<> 0.00` but it still returns `0.00`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for `ISNULL()`

Configure a shared variable to store the latest value that passes through it, but *only* update its value when `NOT(ISNULL({yourValue}))`. Then when you reach the end of your report, you'll get the most recent/last nonnull value.

Comment: Using `NOT(ISNULL({Command.percent}))` only returns me a False value. How would I go about using that in a running total? @4444

Comment: @michaelg The purpose of NOT ISNULL is to determine, true or false, should I update the shared variable? If value *isn't* null, your code should put it into the shared variable. If it *is* null, your code can safely ignore it and do nothing.

Comment: I am not very familiar with putting values into shared variables. Would I declare the variable as part of a formula @4444

Comment: @michaelg Correct